# redirecting in php site

Tags: php

i`m implementing a login function using php. After user logout it should redirect to index.php page twice. if not after user click logout button first time it redirect to index.php page.but in navigation bar it is showing user is still logged.

My form is as follows.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger " style="margin-top: 10px;" name="logout" value="Logout"></form>
```

my php code is as follows

```
if(isset($_POST["logout"])) {
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
}
```

as above code it is not redirect to index.php page twice. why is that?

Comment: if your real code has the closing `</form>` tag, add it to your question. Otherwise, if that is your real code, then it's missing and will contribute ot its failure. Also make sure that the session has been started for all pages using sessions. This comment is most likely what will lead you to a solution.

Comment: you also tagged as mysql which I removed; no code to support the question.

Comment: I didn't understand the "twice" thing.

Comment: @Fred i update the question

Comment: sorry but your question is unclear. Re-read/reload my comment(s) and tell me what you're using and NOT using. If that is your full and real code, then it's obvious... your code failed because of not starting the session inside all pages using sessions. To be more specific `session_start();` I can't guess here, sorry.

Comment: Add `exit()` right after `header()`.

Comment: No need to `exit()` after `header` function, since it's a `Location` one and does nothing after its parsing. It's probably something with his sessions like @Fred-ii- said, it's up to OP's to decide if he wants to improve his question with further details.

Answer (score 0):

See flowing code

```
if(isset($_POST["logout"])) {
session_destroy();
  header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.php"); /* Redirect browser */
  exit();
}
```

OR

```
$url = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.php';

if (headers_sent()){
      die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="' . $url . '";</script>');
    }else{
      header('Location: ' . $url);
      die();
    }
```